# Reading and saving data to a Django model

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to understand how to save data into my Django models. I have a form that display Questions and choices from my models. I want the user to answer the question and to be saved in the Answer model. Here are my models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="this is a caption")
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
    vis_image = models.ImageField(default= "this is an image", null=False, blank=False, upload_to="static/study/img")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Condition(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Participant(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    condition = models.ForeignKey(Condition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Answer(models.Model):
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    completion_time = models.FloatField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def LPSC_VIEW1(request):
    participant=Participant.objects.get(user=request.user)
    #GET the first question based on the participant condition
    if participant.condition.name == 'LPN':
        First_question= Question.objects.get(id=1)
        all_choices = First_question.choices.all()
        context = {'First_question': First_question, 'all_choices': all_choices}
        return render(request, 'study/FirstQN.html', context)
    else:
        First_question= Question.objects.get(id=11)
        all_choices = First_question.choices.all()
        context = {'First_question': First_question, 'all_choices': all_choices}
        return render(request, 'study/FirstQSC.html', context)
```

FirstQN.html

```
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label>
                            {{First_question}}
                        </label>
                        <img src="{{ First_question.vis_image.url }}" style= "height: 600px; width: 960px">

                        {% for i in all_choices %}
                            <input type="radio" id="choice" name="choice" value="{{ choice.id }}">
                            <label for="choice">{{ i.choice_text }}</label>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href = server_url +'/study/LPSC_VIEW2'">
                    </form>
```

my question is can I use the same view to read data from the database and save data submitted from the user on the same view? or do I have to create a new view but then wouldn't that result in redundancy? I have read about saving data from forms but couldn't understand how to apply it on my case where the form itself is fetched from the database. At the moment the code above all works fine.

Comment: Normally if you submit data that should create a new record, you use a POST request. It is very common to do that to the same view where you first rendered the form.

Comment: Using django forms comes in very handy here. You can just check for the request method in your view "if request.method == 'POST':" here you can then validate your users input and save the form. You can read all about it in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/
Using forms for compicated choices might look a bit difficult but it is really worth to get into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the view, and is a standard way of doing it using function-based views. Just check the `request.method` as follows:

```
@login_required
def LPSC_VIEW1(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
         # do your code for saving the answers here
    ... the rest of your code
```